# How to change individual columns’ widths of a multicol inside a minipage, all inside of multicol?

Tags: spacing, formatting, minipage, multicol

I have an outer multicol, then mini pages inside the columns.

Inside my minipage, I have multicols. But **how to change the width of the *inside* multicols in *each* minipage** (ie, independent of all other multicols in other minipages)?  And, without affecting the width of the global multicol?

To be specific: any method of setting the col width will be fine: manual adjustment of each col, or as some percentages (ie 50%/50% or 30%/40%/30% etc)

Thanks!

**Output with no column width setting:**
[image]

**Output with attempted column width setting (fails):**
[image]

**Desired output: Changed colwidths of first minipage’s multicol:**
[image]

**MWE:**

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[landscape]{geometry}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{tikz}

\advance\topmargin-.8in
\advance\textheight3in
\advance\textwidth3in
\advance\paperheight1.5in 
\advance\oddsidemargin-1.5in
\advance\evensidemargin-1.5in
\parindent0pt
\parskip2pt

\usepackage{fourier}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}

\begin{center}{\huge{\textbf{Notes}}}
\end{center}
\begin{multicols*}{3}

\tikzset{mybox/.style={draw=black, fill=white, very thick,
    rectangle, rounded corners, inner sep=10pt, inner ysep=10pt},
        fancytitle/.style={fill=black, text=white, font=\bfseries}
    }

%------------ Box 1 ---------------
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node [mybox] (box){%
    \small
    \begin{minipage}{0.3\textwidth}
    \setlength{\columnsep}{-2.5cm}
    \begin{multicols*}{2}
    This is a sentence, it keeps going and going and going and going and going.\\
    This is a shorter sentence, it stops here.
    \newpage
    This is a sentence, it keeps going and going and going and going and going.\\
    This is a shorter sentence, it stops here.
    \end{multicols*}
    \end{minipage}
};
\node[fancytitle, right=10pt] at (box.north west) {Box 1};
\end{tikzpicture}

%------------ Really long box to fill up the rest of column ---------------
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node [mybox] (box){%
    \Huge
    \begin{minipage}{0.3\textwidth}
    asdf asdf asdf asdf asdf asdf asdf asdf
    asdf asdf asdf asdf asdf asdf asdf asdf
    asdf asdf asdf asdf asdf asdf asdf asdf
    asdf asdf asdf asdf asdf asdf asdf asdf
    asdf asdf asdf asdf asdf asdf asdf asdf
    asdf asdf asdf asdf asdf asdf asdf asdf
    asdf asdf asdf asdf asdf asdf asdf asdf
    asdf asdf asdf asdf asdf asdf asdf asdf
    asdf asdf asdf asdf asdf asdf asdf asdf
    asdf asdf asdf asdf asdf asdf asdf asdf
    \end{minipage}
};
\node[fancytitle, right=10pt] at (box.north west) {Really long box to fill up rest of column};
\end{tikzpicture}


%------------ Box 3 ---------------
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node [mybox] (box){%
    \Huge
    \begin{minipage}{0.3\textwidth}
    Some typing here. This box should be as usual/expected.
    \end{minipage}
};
\node[fancytitle, right=10pt] at (box.north west) {Box 3};
\end{tikzpicture}


\end{multicols*}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I think what you mean is that you want to use different widths for the columns in `multicol`. The fact that it is embedded inside a minipage (which itself is embedded inside another `multicol`) does not play a role at all. Check out the answer.

Comment: If that was what you meant, then your question is a bit misleading. Such things either work or don't at all. You can think of them as context free. If it is embedded inside another thing or rotated or ... does not have any effect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you cannot set the widths for `multicol`. Instead, you should use the `vwcol` (vari­able-width mul­ti­ple text columns) package.

Include it by `\usepackage{vwcol}` and use it such below:

```
\begin{vwcol}[_Conditions_] 

\end{vwcol}
```

In your case, I will use `widths={0.3,0.7}, sep=.8cm, justify=flush,rule=0pt` as the conditions.

**MWE:**

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[landscape]{geometry}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{vwcol}
\usepackage{tikz}

\advance\topmargin-.8in
\advance\textheight3in
\advance\textwidth3in
\advance\paperheight1.5in 
\advance\oddsidemargin-1.5in
\advance\evensidemargin-1.5in
\parindent0pt
\parskip2pt

\usepackage{fourier}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}

\begin{center}{\huge{\textbf{Notes}}}
\end{center}
\begin{multicols*}{3}

\tikzset{mybox/.style={draw=black, fill=white, very thick,
    rectangle, rounded corners, inner sep=10pt, inner ysep=10pt},
        fancytitle/.style={fill=black, text=white, font=\bfseries}
    }

%------------ Box 1 ---------------
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node [mybox] (box){%
    \small
    \begin{minipage}{0.3\textwidth}
    \setlength{\columnsep}{-2.5cm}
    
     \begin{vwcol}[widths={0.3,0.7},
 sep=.8cm, justify=flush,rule=0pt] 
This is a sentence, it keeps going and going and going and going and going.\\
    This is a shorter sentence, it stops here.
        \newpage
    \noindent This is a sentence, it keeps going and going and going and going and going.\\
    This is a shorter sentence, it stops here.
 \end{vwcol} 
    \end{minipage}
};
\node[fancytitle, right=10pt] at (box.north west) {Box 1};
\end{tikzpicture}

%------------ Really long box to fill up the rest of column ---------------
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node [mybox] (box){%
    \Huge
    \begin{minipage}{0.3\textwidth}
    asdf asdf asdf asdf asdf asdf asdf asdf
    asdf asdf asdf asdf asdf asdf asdf asdf
    asdf asdf asdf asdf asdf asdf asdf asdf
    asdf asdf asdf asdf asdf asdf asdf asdf
    asdf asdf asdf asdf asdf asdf asdf asdf
    asdf asdf asdf asdf asdf asdf asdf asdf
    asdf asdf asdf asdf asdf asdf asdf asdf
    asdf asdf asdf asdf asdf asdf asdf asdf
    asdf asdf asdf asdf asdf asdf asdf asdf
    asdf asdf asdf asdf asdf asdf asdf asdf
    \end{minipage}
};
\node[fancytitle, right=10pt] at (box.north west) {Really long box to fill up rest of column};
\end{tikzpicture}


%------------ Box 3 ---------------
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node [mybox] (box){%
    \Huge
    \begin{minipage}{0.3\textwidth}
    Some typing here. This box should be as usual/expected.
    \end{minipage}
};
\node[fancytitle, right=10pt] at (box.north west) {Box 3};
\end{tikzpicture}


\end{multicols*}
\end{document}
```

Which produces the results below:
[image: MWE Results]